# Order of Certificates in Windows Popup

Tags: certificate

So when you go to a site via internet explorer/chrome that requires a certificate (such as from a smart card), is there any way to change the order of the certificates displayed?

I've found it's based on expiration date, however all 3 expire at the same time.

Mostly this is to force users to select the correct cert which is not displayed right away but instead forces them to go to more choices...